# Is there a way to randomize increments/decrements between two integers in java?

Tags: java, random, increment, decrement

I'm learning Java and need to make a vehicle simulator.

A vehicle can move one step each round either vertically or horizontally.

`b) move method increments or decrements either x or y coordinates by 1.`

I don't know if my unfinished code will be of any help, but here it is:

```
package vehicleSimulator;

public class Vehicle {
    int h; // horizontal coordinate instead of x
    int v; // vertical coordinate instead of y
    boolean isAlive = true; 

    public Vehicle(int h, int v, boolean isAlive) {
        this.h = h;
        this.v = v;
        this.isAlive = isAlive;
    }

    public void moveVehicle() {
        if (isAlive == true) {
            // ++ or -- x or y
        }

    }
```

Any help or links to sites that can help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into randomness in Java?

Comment: The textbook I have for this class only talks about how to randomly generate an integer. I can't find anything else on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a random integer value and perform mod operation and update x/y accordingly..

Sample could be:

```
int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(11111, 99999);

if (random % 7 == 0) { 
    x++;
} else if (random % 6 == 2) {
    y--;
} // and so on...
```

Use different mod value for other operations...

Comment: why do you need `%` if you can just use nextInt(1,6) or even nextBoolean in this case?